# My axios refresh token is success but after token is refreshed it wont refetch the failed request

Tags: javascript, axios

So i have made use of axios interceptors to detect for 401 error and tried to refetch the access_token. I did it but after the token is refreshed it wont re-request the failed task.

Here is my response interceptor code.

```
/**
 * Axios Response Handler
 */
loggedAxios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(response);
    }),
  (error) => {
    const originalConfig = error.config;
    let auths = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("htAuth"));

    // Access Token was expired
    if (error?.response?.status === 401 && auths !== undefined && loop < 1) {
      //Refresh token
      let rtkn = localStorage.getItem("rTkn");

      if (!isRefreshing) {
        loop++;
        isRefreshing = true;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          let payload = {
            refresh: rtkn,
          };
          refreshTokenApi(payload) //Getting new access token
            .then((res) => {
              loggedAxios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
                "Bearer " + res.data?.access;
              originalConfig.headers["Authorization"] =
                "Bearer " + res.data?.access;
              onRrefreshed(res.data?.access);
              resolve(loggedAxios(originalConfig));
              auths.token = res.data?.access;
              // localStorage.setItem("rTkn", res.data?.access); //Setting new rTkn
              localStorage.setItem("htAuth", JSON.stringify(auths)); //Updating user with new access token
              failedQueue = [];
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              reject(error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
              isRefreshing = false;
            });
        });
      }

      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        subscribeTokenRefresh((token) => {
          originalConfig.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
          resolve(axios(originalConfig));
        });
      });
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

I tried a lot but i am really frustrated cause I am waiting 20min for the token to expire and recheck. Please save my day.

Comment: What version of Axios are you using? There's been a lot of bugs in every version over 1.0.0

Comment: @Phil seems like its v^1.1.3

Comment: Yep, that's one of the bad ones. Try either 0.27.2 or 1.2.1.

Comment: @Phil wow i downgraded to v0.27.2 and it now works, thank you Phil for the quick response you saved my day where I was waiting every 20min to wait token expiry. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a known bug in Axios. See https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5283